# Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I created a computed observable rather than having a extra code in the view and now when I run the page I get an error in the console stating:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined"

Here is what I have so far:

```
self.email = ko.observable(initialData.userEmail || '');
self.emailMailto = ko.computed(function(){ return 'mailto:'+self.email();});
```

I know that email observable is returning the appropriate data but I am not sure if it is referring to `emailMailto` as undefined.

this is my view:

```
<p><a data-bind="attr:{href:emailMailto},text:email"></a></p>
```

Comment: The error doesn't look like it corresponds with the code snippet you provided. There is no reference to `.concat`

Comment: @War10ck will this is the only change i made adding the computed. it was running fine but after the computed it gave me this error.

Comment: That may be the case, but something else had to have changed. Does removing the `.computed` cause the error to disappear? I'd be surprised if it did.

Comment: @war10ck the error appears once i click on the email link which should open the mailto

Comment: Can you examine the anchor tag with your console debugger `<F12>` and post the value of the anchor's `href` attribute...

Comment: there's gotta be something else, I just put together this fiddle and everything works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6yj466ny/

Comment: @dperry not sure what else it could be. When i place the mailto into the view and i click on the link it works and open fine it is only when i placed it in a computed that i am seeing this error. I guess i have to play around and see.

Comment: @072et does a normal mailto (not knockout-generated) work? could be a browser issue.

Comment: @072et do you have any other click handlers defined for the link? jquery, for example?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is not directly related to your problem.

What's happening here is that some code wants to use the `.concat()` method on a variable.

`.concat()` is a prototype of `Array`, which means that the code in question expects an array.

`undefined` means that, instead of an array, nothing has been passed to the code. This can mean two things:

- Either an expected function parameter has not been passed, e.g. the method is declared as `function doSomething(withValue)` and you are calling it as `function doSomething()` (without a value).
- Or the code tries to process a property of an object which is not set.

As the code causing the error has been working before and you apparently didn't modify it, I would guess that it's the latter case: You're tossing around an object which is missing a property that should be there and should be an array.